# Drupal: How to add JavaScript value to hidden form component

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-webform

I want to get the user screen size as one of my hidden fields.

In pure HTML, I can get the input value as JavaScript, e.g.:

```
document.write(screen.width + " x " + screen.height)
```

If I set[input format] of the page to [full html] or [php code], if I set the component value to -

```
<script>document.write(screen.width + " x " + screen.height);</script>
```

the SCRIPT tags are omitted, and the quote signs becomes " . It seems that the [value] field is transformed to safe HTML entities.

Is there a way to add a hidden form component with JavaScript value, in Drupal webforms?

EDIT: Solved:

```
1 - Copy the original
...sites/all/modules/webform/webform-form.tpl.php 
to
...sites/all/themes/myTheme/webform-form-myFormNodeId.tpl.php 


2 - Add the following lines to webform-form-myFormNodeId.tpl.php

  echo "<script>";
  echo "document.getElementById('edit-submitted-userscreen').value = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;";
  echo "</script>";


3 - admin/settings/performance : [Clear cached data]
```

---

Edit:
I can add some PHP values as

```
%server[HTTP_USER_AGENT]
```

How do I add JavaScript values?

Edit 2:
I tried changing the node [input format] to [php code]
and the following [form component][value], but all of them did not work:

```
1 - drupal_add_js(screen.width + " x " + screen.height);
2 - <script>document.write(screen.width + " x " + screen.height);</script>
3 - <?php echo "<script language=\"javascript\">" . "document.write (screen.width + ' x ' + screen.height);" . "</script>"; ?>

4 - full html + 
<script>
jQuery('#edit-submitted-userscreen').val(screen.width + 'x' + screen.height);
</script>
=> in View Page Source, I see:
<input type="hidden" name="submitted[userscreen]" id="edit-submitted-userscreen" value="
jQuery(&#039;#edit-submitted-userscreen&#039;).val(screen.width + &#039;x&#039; + screen.height);


"  />
```

[SCRIPT tags are replaced with NewLineChar ???]

=> so when I fill in the form, I receive email with the original string:

```
userScreen: jQuery('#edit-submitted-userscreen').val(screen.width + 'x' + screen.height);
```

Comment: The second variant with script should work.

Comment: with the second variant, when I "view source" the SCRIPT tags are omitted, so I get the inner string as the value [document.write(screen.width + " x " + screen.height);]

Comment: Try to put "Full HTML" input format, that should work.

Comment: I changed [input format] from [php code] to [full HTML], used second variant, and still when [view source] of the page, there are no SCRIPT tags, and " becomes &quot, and there is an empty line before closing the INPUT tag : . . . id="edit-submitted-userscreen" value="document.write(screen.width + &quot; x &quot; + screen.height); 

"  />
[Thanks for your help!]

Comment: You must NOT put javascript inside attribute value of hidden field.

Comment: because it is hidden? or because it is javascript? is it written somewhere?

Comment: Try to put code from two of my EDITED options in my answer. Note that in second edit script should go after input tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as:

1) Define a hidden field in your form.

```
$form['resolution'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden'
);
```

2) Apply value with jQuery to your field.

```
$('#edit-resolution').val(screen.width + " x " + screen.height);
```

**EDITED**

Try to provide this value to your textarea with `Full HTML` mode enabled.

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted[userscreen]" id="edit-submitted-userscreen" value="" />

<script>
jQuery('#edit-submitted-userscreen').val(screen.width + 'x' + screen.height);
</script>
```

**SECOND EDIT**

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted[userscreen]" id="edit-submitted-userscreen" value="" />
<script>document.getElementById('edit-submitted-userscreen').value = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;</script>
```

Comment: I add the form component using the GUI. What should be the [Value] field of this form component? [$val(screen.width + " x " + screen.height] ??

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you mean?

Comment: till now, I created the forms using the [form component][edit] button. where should I write the code you offered me?

Comment: =) ok, what's the ID of your field which you added?

Comment: in view-source: id="edit-submitted-userscreen", I only entered id: userscreen

Comment: The jquery also didnot work. The original SCRIPT tags are replaced with NewLineChar . How can I tell this field to NOT transform its value to "safe html" ???